# Desktop Application that uses RSS feeds

Tags: c#, rss, feed

I need to develop a desktop application that shows the contents of RSS feeds taken from other websites. I have never worked withe RSS feeds before. How can this be done? Can I use C# to develop the desktop application?

Comment: Google is a wonderful resource for code.

Comment: http://wpfrssfeedreader.codeplex.com/

Comment: [Stackoverflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553)

Comment: unfortunately there is no question in your post. "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. (You are more than welcome to have such discussions in our real time web chat.) However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."... "Expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development, ask on Programmers." via stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RSS feed is just XML. Google the RSS specification. In C# you could do something like:

```
XmlReader rdr;
Stream strm;
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    strm = client.OpenRead(uri);
    rdr = XmlReader.Create(strm);
    while (!rdr.EOF) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```